# where can I find a machine-readable list of the most popular users on twitter?

Tags: twitter, rss, feed

I'm interested in building a simple demo and need a list of top twitter users. Is there a web site that offers a JSON or RSS feed (or otherwise easily parseable list) of the top 1000 twitter users by number of followers. Is there a web site that offers something like this? (I know I can scrape one of the many sites like Twitaholic but I'd rather not bother with that if there is an easier alternative.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Twitter Counter](http://twittercounter.com/) , they also have a nice [REST api](http://twittercounter.com/pages/api?ref=footer) that I like. Lady Gaga is #1 of course.

**Edit based on comment**

Here is a Yahoo Pipe for Top5 which can probably be edited for more

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=10ba4ad51d85cbf06d97236a2a291ac6

---

http://twittercounter.com/

http://twittercounter.com/pages/api?ref=footer

Comment: I see an API to get info on a single user, but don't see anything for the top 1000 list.

Comment: i edited the answer. Check out the Yahoo Pipe which lists at least 5. 1000 may be beyond the limit, I'm not sure.